# How to make a pdf download on a button click with react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is what I've tried:

```
<button className="button">
  <a
     className="button"
     href="../assets/Resume/ResumeOfficial.pdf"
     download
     >
    Download Resume
  </a>
</button>
```

It does try to download but it cannot find the file, yet I'm sure (like 99% unless I made some dumb mistake) that the address is correct.

Comment: The `href` path you're using is based on the *source code*. However, when the react app gets built then the output files are usually bundled into one JS file at the root of the directory. So check the output folder of your app build and see where the built bundle is and where the assets are relative to it

Comment: First of all, `a` element is not allowed inside a `button` element, nor the opposite.
But I don't think that's causing the problem. Most likely the path is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import same file in some variable and then you can use that variable in href it might work.

find below example:

```
<a href="variable_name" download>
```

Comment: This does work but it has to be href = {variable_name}

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button className="button">
    <a className="button" href="../assets/Resume/ResumeOfficial.pdf" download = "ResumeOfficial.pdf">
      Download Resume
    </a>
</button>
```

so this should solve your problem, generally for downloading .pdf always double check

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

Comment: this doesnt work but the other response does. thank you still for trying

Comment: Is that react or vanilla html?

Answer (score 0):

try it this should solve your problem. Add `href` and `download` param.

```
<a href={require("../path/to/file.pdf")} download="myFile">Download file</a>
```